# Change Doctrine ORM mapping from XML to Annotations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

We setup our project and somehow my partner made it so that the mapping was done with the .orm.xml files.

Before figuring this out I thought the mapping was annotations and spent many hours and headaches trying to figure out why my mappings weren't working.

Since I was ignorant and continued adding annotations I'd like to switch the mapping from XML to annotations. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it here:

[Doctrine Mapping Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration)

You have to explicitly name your mapping and specify Annotation.

Comment: What exactely did you change in your config @John the Ripper ?

Comment: Under `mappings` you have a `mapping_name` and under that you have `type`. Change the `type`.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad I could help someone save the time I spent on this issue.